# Print string of words formatting similar to text output from `ls` command

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Is there any command that can print any string of words e.g.

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Aenean arcu
>   dui commodo nec tortor ut posuere malesuada magna"

to be dynamically formatted as columns similar to text output from `ls` command e.g.

```
~$ls
Applications   Dropbox        Pictures       test2          playground
Desktop        Library        Public         test3          programs
Documents      Movies         VirtualBoxVMs  macports       projects
Downloads      Music          test1          test4
```

Number of columns should correspond to size of the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tr` to replace spaces by newlines. Then use `column -cXXX` to format the output for a terminal `XXX` characters wide, and use `tput cols` to find out how wide the terminal actually is:

```
echo "..." | tr ' ' '\n' | column -c$(tput cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

`column -t` needs rows separated by newline, so we can insert newline between specified words to create a row.
So:

1. I used `sed 's/\(\([^ ]* \)\{5\}\)/\1\n/g'` to insert a newline each 5 words
2. I used  `column -t` to create a table

```
$ echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Aenean arcu dui commodo nec tortor ut posuere malesuada magna" | sed 's/\(\([^ ]* \)\{5\}\)/\1\n/g' | column -t -o$'\t'
Lorem       ipsum       dolor   sit     amet
consectetur adipiscing  elit    Aenean  arcu
dui         commodo     nec     tortor  ut
posuere     malesuada   magna
```

However the may be a better solution, one which takes the terminal width into account.

Comment: "5 words" sounds too "ad hoc" to me. I expected format to be dynamics corresponding to the terminal size such as the output from `ls` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fmt` to achieve that:, Example:

```
echo "Lorem ipsum .. .. .. . . magna" |fmt 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
Aenean arcu dui commodo nec tortor ut posuere malesuada
magna
```

> -w, --width=WIDTH         maximum line width (default of 75 columns)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with the printf and the column options.

easy method like that:

```
printf "%-8s\n" a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt e.txt f.txt g.txt h.txt i.txt j.txt k.txt l.txt m.txt n.txt o.txt p.txt q.txt r.txt s.txt t.txt u.txt v.txt w.txt x.txt y.txt z.txt | column
```

Or in a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

for aFileNames in a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt e.txt f.txt g.txt h.txt i.txt j.txt k.txt l.txt m.txt n.txt o.txt p.txt q.txt r.txt s.txt t.txt u.txt v.txt w.txt x.txt y.txt z.txt
do 
  printf "%-8s\n" $aFileNames
done | column
```

---

Output will look like that:

```
a.txt        j.txt        s.txt
b.txt        k.txt        t.txt
c.txt        l.txt        u.txt
d.txt        m.txt        v.txt
e.txt        n.txt        w.txt
f.txt        o.txt        x.txt
g.txt        p.txt        y.txt
h.txt        q.txt        z.txt
i.txt        r.txt
```

If you want you can change the `"%-8s"` value to change the number of columns displayed.
Valid values are: `"-4",  "-8", "-16", "-32", etc...`

You can find more infos about it if you type `column -help` in the terminal and here:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/column
- https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/using/column